# My firebase callable cloud function is called twice (when I called only once), how can I avoid my flutter app from failure?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to make a callable function in firebase, but when I call it from my flutter app it is called twice.
The Issue is, I am calling the function while sending some parameters to perform on by cloud function.
The automatic second call initiates with null parameter, which causes chaos because the function return empty list.
Here is my function code.
[callable function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D1Im.png)

```js
exports.getItem = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  //  Data NULL Check
  if (data == null) {
    console.log("NULL DATA RECIEVED");
    console.log(`null event id ${context.eventID}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`event id ${context.eventID}`);
    const itemList = [];
    console.log("Begin...............");
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data["closet"]);
    console.log(data["from"].toString());
    console.log(data["count"].toString());
    const querySnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection("t_shirt").get();
    querySnapshot.doc.forEach((doc)=>{
      itemList.push(doc);
    });
    console.log(itemList.length);
    if (itemList.length > 0) {
      return itemList;
    }
  }
});
```

As I know I have to return something, because it's a promise.
So If I return empty list if the data is null, the app recieves empty list, while the first call is still fetching the data and making a list.

Comment: Please place your code in your question with the appropriate language identifier instead of using screenshots.

Comment: here I've added

Answer (score 0):

Okay the issue was it's **querySnapshot.docs** and not **querySnapshot.doc**